# Moving Title or text in application metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to add a moving text or moving title im my windows 8 application.
How can i do this with XAML?? 
Here is an example with HTML: http://www.astwinds.com/astuces/html/textedefilant.html

Best regards

Comment: <TextBox HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox/>. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry i need a moving text, i need that my text move alone from left to right

Comment: do you mean a control similar to marquee?

Comment: yes a control similar to marquee

Comment: google helps you. [codeproject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48267/Making-a-Simple-Marquee-Text-Control-Drip-Animatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Surely there are more.

Add a call to MoveMarqueeText function to the Composition Target Rending event in your OnNavigatedTo event.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     CompositionTarget.Rendering += MoveMarqueeText;
}
```

Add a function which will remove first character of string and append it to the end.

```
void MoveMarqueeText(object sender, object e)
{
     Marquee.Text = Marquee.Text.Substring(1)  + Marquee.Text.Substring(0,1);
}
```

With XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="woot hey woot woot hey woot hey woot woot hey woot hey woot woot hey" Width="250" x:Name="Marquee" TextWrapping="NoWrap">
```

To slow it down add a conditional statement and a counter increment in your MoveMarqueeText function, to slow it down to time based, use a timer in your conditional.

Comment: it's working, but it's not good working. The text is flickering.